# What does [{}].concat() in JS do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is something I could look up, but I have no idea what that's called much less what to search for. It'd be great to have a pointer!

Some background, we're fetching an array of objects from an API and saving them in a state variable, "notes" which is being passed into the function below.

So here's the code:

```
function renderNotesList(notes) {
  return [{}].concat(notes).map((note, i) =>
    i !== 0 ? (
      // Do something
    ) : (
      // Do something else
  )
}
```

I simplified the code above to just

```
function renderNotesList(notes) {
        console.log([{}].concat(notes))
    }
```

And this is the output in dev tools console before and after the function is run

```
0: Object { id: "1", note_text: "I am the first test note" }
​
1: Object { id: "2", note_text: "I am a new test note" }
​
length: 2
```

After

```
0: Object {  }
​
1: Object { id: "1", note_text: "I am the first test note" }
​
2: Object { id: "2", note_text: "I am a new test note" }
​
length: 3
```

I don't understand *why* the [tutorial](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/call-the-list-api.html) is doing this. It seems that `[{}].concat(notes)` just adds an extra empty object?

I have looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat but it doesn't appear to have anything similar to this. Or at least, I don't know which part is relevant.

Comment: `[{}]` indeed makes an array with a single empty object. Not sure why that is needed, though - it seems wrong. It might be an error or it might be intentional to leave an empty space in the beginning or something. EDIT: Ah, I see - it's indeed intentional, there is a different content for `i == 0`

Comment: Ah right, okay so the tutorial wants the first row of the notes list to be a "create new note" clickable row. So it was correct, I just didn't put the two together. Also the syntax is quite new to me so I wasn't sure of what it did.  Could you put your comment down as an answer so I can select it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right `[{}]` does indeed just create an array with an empty object in it, so `[{}].concat(notes)` will create an array with an empty object and the contents of the `notes` array afterwards.

This is done on purpose, since the code then changes each element through [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). However, it uses special logic, where all `notes` elements will be used to display information for them, while the first element will be a link with text "Create a new note" and clicking it will add another note.

It doesn't matter what the first item is, the check is done based on the index `i !== 0` which will execute the *first* code branch for any `note` (anything that's not the first element` and the *second* code branch only for the first element (the empty object).

Answer (score 1):

The reason they are doing that is because concat is a prototype of an array and you cant use it without an array as a prefix in the beginning

take this for example

```js
  const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
  const array3 = array1.concat(array2);

  console.log(array3);
```

So concatenate joins two arrays, Any other data type it wont work without an array for the starting element . That is why they giving a blank array in the start

Comment: The array is not empty. The question is about the empty object added to it.

Answer (score 0):

`[{}].concat(...)` starts with an array with a single element, an empty object literal, in it, and concatenates another array into it.

```
function renderNotesList(notes) {
  return [{}].concat(notes).map((note, i) =>
    i !== 0 ? (
      // Do something
    ) : (
      // Do something else
  )
}
```

In the above code they are clearly treating the zeroth element differently than the rest concatenated from the passed argument. Without seeing what the "do something" or "do something else" code is, or what tutorial you're working from it is hard to say other than this simplifies the map function later.

```js
function renderNotesList(notes) {
  return [{}].concat(notes).map((note, i) =>
    i !== 0 ? (
      { ...note,  extra: 'This is not the first element so we inject a property.' }
    ) : (
      { firstElement: 'This is the first element.' }
    )
  )
}

const notes = [{ note: 'note 1' },{ note: 'note 2' }];

console.log(renderNotesList(notes));
```

I would like to add that a cleaner/clearer way to accomplish this would be to instead use the spread operator

```
function renderNotesList(notes) {
  return [
    { /* do the something else */ },
    ...notes.map(note => { /* do the something */ }),
  ];
}
```